# Let $x'=x \ln(1+x^2)$ with $x(0)=1$. why the maximal solutions are defined in whole line?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let  $x'=x \ln(1+x^2)$ with $x(0)=1$. Why the maximal solutions are defined in whole line?

**Comment:** Any idea is welcome. The existence theorem guarantees the solution, however why is it defined in $\mathbb{R}$?
The function seems to be monotone increasing and positive.

Comment: All you have to prevent is a blow-up in finite time. All we need is to bound the solution from above. But this equation is separable, so it is easy to get explicite upper bound, preventing the solution from blowing-up.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks, this is helpful to understand the intuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint: The solution is given implicitly by
$$
\int_1^{x(t)} \frac{dx}{x \ln(1+x^2)} = t
.
$$
Can you show that $\int_1^0 (\cdots) = -\infty$ and $\int_1^\infty (\cdots) = +\infty$?